# How can I sum number of rows of a table in SQL ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by, where-clause

I have the follow instruction on SQL ORACLE:

```
SELECT COUNT(FE_DAY)
FROM TI_DATE
WHERE (FE_MO = 02 AND FE_YEAR in ('2011', '2012'))
GROUP BY FE_DAY
```

In this instruction effectively obtain like SQL Answer a list of number that they sum=10 .But How can I don't show rows .I need only show the row's sum=10

I tried to apply the follow SQL instruction also:

```
SELECT SUM(COUNT(FE_DAY))
FROM TI_DATE
WHERE (FE_MO = 02 AND FE_YEAR in ('2011', '2012'))
GROUP BY FE_DAY
```

But the answer was 57, different of the number of rows, that I need.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly what you want, you actually don't need the `GROUP BY` clause; you can just write:

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
  FROM ti_date
 WHERE fe_mo = 2
   AND fe_year IN ('2011', '2012')
;
```

Comment: In others words from TI_DATE I need to obtain the numbers of rows(the numbers of days of february '2' in the 2011 year and 2012 year).Thanks

Comment: @ChristianMagro: The query that I posted will return the total number of records for February 2011 and February 2012. Is that not what you want?

Comment: Yes, that's ok.Excuse me.I don't see very well that.Thanks for your help.